# Java Apache HTTP Client fails with http request where cURL succeed

Tags: java, curl, httpclient

I'm finding difficult performing a simple http request in Java using apache http client. The request is a simple GET toward the following url http://109.231.121.64:20622/v1/collections/S4C/objects/OpsConfig/data (which is currently up and running). The request succeed using curl like in the following:

```
curl -v -X GET http://109.231.121.64:20622/v1/collections/S4C/objects/OpsConfig/data > s4cOpsInitModel.xml
```

And this is the output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache    
*   Trying 109.231.121.64...    
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current    
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:----:--:--     0* Connected to 109.231.121.64 (109.231.121.64) port 20622 (#0)
> GET /v1/collections/S4C/objects/OpsConfig/data HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 109.231.121.64:20622
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< connection: keep-alive
* Server Cowboy is not blacklisted
< server: Cowboy
< date: Tue, 08 Sep 2015 08:11:22 GMT
< content-length: 2349
< content-type: application/octet-stream
< 
{ [data not shown]
100  2349  100  2349    0     0  27819      0 --:--:-- --:--:----:--:-- 27964
* Connection #0 to host 109.231.121.64 left intact
```

but then when doing the same in Java an http error status 500 s returned. Here is the code I'm using:

```
try {


        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
            "http://109.231.121.64:20622/v1/collections/S4C/objects/OpsConfig/data");


        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
               + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I had a look on google but I cannot figured out what's happening. My guess is that something is wrong with the accepted content type, but I tried to set different kind of content type without succeeding. Do you have any idea about what I'm doing wrong? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: curl -verbose -silent? Why?

Comment: Please check/provide the output/verbose from curl.

Comment: What "problems" did you get? Please add any exception stacktrace to the post

Comment: Sorry for call them problems, I edited the post and also added the output of curl -v.

Answer (score 0):

Solved and it seemed it was related to the accepted content type. Adding the following header to the http request make it work.

```
getRequest.setHeader("accept", "*/*");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today too but for a different reason. I was racking my brain on it. It was when I was making http requests to sharepoint.

Curl - worked fine. Http client did not.

It took a long time to realize it but it was because the `FedAuth` and `rtFa` cookies I am sending in the requests manually are somehow interfering with the cookies that are saved into the cookie store and sent back. So the first request would work fine, then the second request would error out.

The solution was to clear the cookie store prior to every request, or to just not set the rtfa fedauth cookies in the request if they are already in the cookie store.